# Concatenating two images in tiled fashion

Tags: java, image, bufferedimage, graphics2d

So what I'm trying to do is take two images and get a result that looks like a tiling of the two. The size of each tile is set in the program (it's supposed to be user controlled, but I'm going to worry about that later) and the size set will be both the length and height of the square. First I tried to tile one of the images and set the other one as a background image, but when I tried to make the empty tile transparent, it made the whole image that way and there was no tiling in the final image. The way I have it now, the result is just the first image with white boxes where I want the background image to appear.

```
||  ||  ||  ||
  ||  ||  ||  
||  ||  ||  ||
  ||  ||  || 
||  ||  ||  ||
  ||  ||  ||  
||  ||  ||  ||
```

The final picture image should look like a checker board. So like above with "||" being image1 and "  " being image2. Thank you!

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImageOp;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Merging {
static BufferedImage background;
static BufferedImage foreground;

public static void main(String[] args) {    
            // load source images
            try {
            foreground = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\Users\\Owner\\Desktop\\CSCI1302\\Project 2\\sample1.png"));
            background = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\Users\\Owner\\Desktop\\CSCI1302\\Project 2\\sample2.png"));
            } catch (IOException e) {}

            // create the new image, canvas size is the max. of both image sizes
            int w = Math.max(foreground.getWidth(), foreground.getWidth());
            int h = Math.max(foreground.getHeight(), foreground.getHeight());

            // edit the overlay to delete pixels (vertical stripes)
            Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) foreground.getGraphics();
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) background.getGraphics();

            // edit the overlay to delete pixels (checkers)
            Color c = new Color(1f,0f,0f,.5f ); // tried to set this to checkers for transparency purposes
            int checker = 10;
            for(int row = 0; row <= foreground.getHeight() / checker; row++) {
                for(int col = 0; col <= foreground.getHeight() / checker; col++) {
                    if(row % 2 == 0) {
                        g.fillRect(row*checker, checker*col*2, checker, checker);
                        g2.fillRect(row*checker, checker+checker*col*2, checker, checker);
                    }
                    else {
                        g.fillRect(row*checker, checker+checker*col*2, checker, checker);
                        g2.fillRect(row*checker, checker*col*2, checker, checker);
                    }
                }
            }

            // paint both images, preserving the alpha channels
            BufferedImage combined = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
            Graphics2D g3 = (Graphics2D) combined.getGraphics();
            g3.drawImage(background, 0, 0, null);
            g3.drawImage(foreground, 0, 0, null);

            ImageIcon i1 = new ImageIcon(combined);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, i3);

}
```

Comment: So the result should be ONE large image, where the two input images are painted alternatingly, as tiles, in a checkerboard fashion, each "tile" version of the images having the size of 10x10 (in this example)?

Comment: Yes and the order of the tiles should look like a checkerboard. I edited the document to include what the layout should look like for the most part.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think there are still two ways of interpreting this, but based on the code that you have posted so far, I think this should be what you are looking for:

```
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Merging
{
    static BufferedImage background;
    static BufferedImage foreground;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // load source images
        try
        {
            foreground = ImageIO.read(new File("image0.jpg"));
            background = ImageIO.read(new File("image1.jpg"));
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // create the new image, canvas size is the max. of both image sizes
        int w = Math.max(foreground.getWidth(), foreground.getWidth());
        int h = Math.max(foreground.getHeight(), foreground.getHeight());
        int checker = 10;

        BufferedImage combined = new BufferedImage(w, h,
            BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) combined.getGraphics();
        for (int row = 0; row <= h / checker; row++)
        {
            for (int col = 0; col <= w / checker; col++)
            {
                BufferedImage source = foreground;
                if ((row+col) % 2 == 0)
                {
                    source = background;
                }
                int dx0 = col * checker;
                int dy0 = row * checker;
                int dx1 = dx0 + checker;
                int dy1 = dy0 + checker;
                int sx0 = col * checker;
                int sy0 = row * checker;
                int sx1 = dx0 + checker;
                int sy1 = dy0 + checker;
                g.drawImage(source, dx0, dy0, dx1, dy1, sx0, sy0, sx1, sy1, null);
            }
        }
        ImageIcon i1 = new ImageIcon(combined);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, i1);
    }
}
```

The idea here is to create the output image, and for each "tile" only draw only the parts of (either the first or the second) input image that should be painted at the respective position, using this nifty 10-parameter-`Graphics#drawImage` method

Comment: Thank you so much! That worked! I didn't even think about using all of the parameters